# Not able to start Nifi

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, apache-nifi, apache-nifi-registry

I tried to start Nifi. But context initialization gets failed. How to get rid of this error?

Nifi Version: 1.9.2

```
2019-11-08 19:47:12,206 INFO [main] o.a.nifi.properties.NiFiPropertiesLoader Loaded 152 properties from D:\Git\DIP1\data-integration-platform\nifi-assembly\target\nifi-1.9.2-bin\nifi-1.9.2\.\conf\nifi.properties
2019-11-08 19:47:17,273 ERROR [main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader Context initialization failed
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/WebAppClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/aopalliance/aop/Advice"
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.foundClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:649)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:555)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy89.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Proxy.java:739)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.getProxy(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:122)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean.getProxy(ProxyFactoryBean.java:368)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean.getSingletonInstance(ProxyFactoryBean.java:322)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean.getObject(ProxyFactoryBean.java:246)
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration.lazyBean(AuthenticationConfiguration.java:148)
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManagerBean(AuthenticationConfiguration.java:152)
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration.java:108)
```

Comment: please provide more info: java version, what changes have you done to nifi..

Comment: @daggett 
I am using Java version jdk1.8.0_161.
Yes I have added some custom processors and made some UI changes

Answer (score 0):

There are two likely problems

1. You are blocked from starting Nifi in general
2. Your specific changes to Nifi block you from starting it

To eliminate the first one, please try working with a clean version of Nifi.

If that works, we can conclude the problem lies in your changes. Eliminate all changes and introduce them 1 (or a few) at a time to identify the breaking change and from there one can dig deeper.